# Do 1-additive maps admit tensor products?

Tags: co.combinatorics, measure-theory, tensor-products, boolean-algebras

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a set algebra (or a Boolean algebra). Following Kalton, let me call a function $f\colon \mathcal{F}\to \mathbb R$ $\delta$-*additive* ($\delta \geqslant 0$), whenever $f(\varnothing) = 0$ and

$$| f(A) + f(B) - f(A\cup B) | \leqslant \delta$$

as long as $A\cap B=\varnothing$ for $A,B\in \mathcal{F}$. Surely 0-additive functions are nothing but finitely additive signed measures.

I am interested in the notion of a *tensor product* that would be analogous to a product measure but actually only in a very simplistic setting.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite sets and suppose that $f\colon \wp(X)\to \mathbb R, g\colon \wp(Y)\to\mathbb R$ are 1-additive functions. Is there a function $h\colon \wp(X\times Y)\to \mathbb{R}$ such that

- $h$ is 1-additive,
- $h(A\times B) = f(A)\cdot g(B)\quad (A\subset X, B\subset Y)$.

The problem is, I think, non-trivial as we need some sort of a canonical decomposition of any given set into a union of rectangles, which is highly non-unique. On the other hand, working only with singletons (trivial rectangles) is not good enough to retrieve the tensorial property of $h$.

Comment: I don't know the subject, but from an algebraic point of view, the number of "canonical admissible decompositions" of a given set should depend on the symmetries thereof. I think one should study the group of permutations $\sigma$ of $1$-additive "building blocks" that commute to $f$, $g$ and $h$.

Comment: Hence the requirement is $\sigma(h(A\times B)=h(\sigma(A\times B))=h(\sigma(A)\times\sigma(B))=\sigma(f(A).g(B))=f(\sigma(A)).g(\sigma(B))$.

Comment: Have you tried with some simple cases like X,Y having two elements? Or maybe with arbitrary number of elements but every subset having measure 1?

Comment: I found something that can be useful. The space of such functions is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ for some $N$, and I claim that it is compact and convex. Compactness come from repeated use of the inequality with singleton, that have assigned measure because they are rectangles. Furthermore, a convex combination preserve both the conditions. Thus, you can add the further condition on h having minimum modulo; such function will exist and will be unique provided that there exist a 'tensor' product. This allows to 'glue' solutions by uniqueness on intersection.

Comment: No I mean for the h on the product, so that f and g on X and Y are fixed. In this case you have $h(S) \le \sum_{s \in S} h(s) + n$ and similarly for the other inequality. Isn't it? I am not saying that 1-additive functions are compact but that the space of "possible tensor products" is.

Comment: @AndreaMarino, yes, but the point is to show that such $h$ exists :-) Now, I think it should not be possible in general.

Comment: Well I mean, I was just pointing that this allows to search for a unique tensor product and not "a" tensor product. The approach I was thinking is inductive: cover your big rectangle with the all the maximal proper subrectangles (which are of the form $X \setimus \{x\} \times Y$ and the same for Y). If you take a minimal tensor product  on each rectangle in the sense above, they coincide on sets which are contained in more than one subrectangle. In general this is not true if you take an arbitrary tensor on each subrectangle! Now we are left with trying to extend this to the rest.

Comment: Maybe a reasonable question is: for what $\epsilon$ does there exist the product of two given $\delta$-additive measures?

Comment: @PietroMajer I have not thought about Tomek's question or your modification, but the paper of Kalton and Roberts which is alluded to in the question shows that every $\delta$-additive measure has total variation distance at most $K\delta$ from a $0$-additive measure, where $K$ is some universal constant independent of $\mathcal F$; I think maybe $K=100$ is good enough? (One of the ideas suggested to me by my PhD supervisor was to find a "better" or "more cohomological" proof, but 15 years later I still haven't succeeded)

Comment: @YemonChoi, $K=44.5$ is perfectly fine. ;-)

Comment: Tomek: It's been too long since I read the paper, although MCW did once tell me that he thought a factor of 2 was missing somewhere, and I couldn't remember whether this meant the value stated by K+R was too small or too large :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you guessed in the comments, it does not exist. The idea is the following: you are searching for some values that have small distance from some given values (the one on rectangles). If for example a new value $v$ must be close to some given values $v_1,v_2$, then necessarily $v_1, v_2$ must be close.

Conditions of Delta additivity in each variable is not enough to guarantee that $v_1$ and $v_2$, will be always close. If you want to find a condition, I guess you should do something like you do in elimination theory with equations, but in this "distance" fashion.

An interesting question so would be, mimicking elimination style: if such inequalities are satisfied, does there exist a solution?

Without such conditions there is a counterexample. Take both sets to have 2 elements that we call $x,y$.

In the first one:

- $x$ and $y$ have measure 0;
- $\{x,y\}$ has measure 1.

In the second one:

- $x$ and $y$ have measure $r$;
- $\{x,y\}$ has measure $2r$.

Emptyset has zero measure in both.
Note that singletons in the product has measure zero.

Now take the L-shaped set $L=\{(x,x), (x,y), (y,x) \}$ and suppose it has measure $A$. If we add the last brick to get the rectangle, we have
$$ | A + 0- 2r| \le 1$$

If we take out the the brick $(y,x)$ the rectangle we are left with has projection $x$ on the first set, thus it has measure zero. On balance we get
$$ |A -0-0| \le 1$$

In contradiction with the previous one for big $r$. Also, note that this yield that in general it does not exist a delta additive tensor product for *any* fixed $\delta$, and that even if one of them is a measure the tensor could not exist.

Comment: @Tomek Kania: if you are interested in, I am finding sufficient (maybe also necessary, not sure about it), for the existence of tensor product. The idea basically is the following: you can split a delta additive function in a sum of a measure and a special linear combination of "characteristic" delta functions, which has measure delta on a prescribed subset and zero anywhere else. The tensor product is bilinear, so it is enough to study the tensor product of two characteristic functions (easy), and a measure with a char. I found out that msr * char of a singleton is a measure, and ...

Comment: msr * char of a non singleton subset exist only if the measure is (in modulo) <= 2 (disregarding delta!!) on any set. I am trying to find a formula that works in this case given the condition on the measure.

Comment: Dear Tomek, I haven't received the mail; actually I don't know which addres I have put on my profile. Could you send it to andreamarino95@gmail.com? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I've sent you an email.